# How to track divs scrolling over point on page with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm looking for a very fast solution to a div scrolling problem.

I have a set of divs, like forum posts, that are laid out one on top of the other. As the page scrolls down or up, I'd like to know when one of those divs hit's an arbitrary point on the page.

One way I tried was adding an onScroll event to each item, but as the number of items grow the page really starts to lag.

Anyone know a more efficient way to do this? Thanks /w

Comment: Add onscroll event to window and compare scrollTop with posts position? You can optimize this by cashing positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm new to all this, so may be someone should correct me :)

I propose to

- cache posts position
- caсhe current
- use binary search

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zYe8M/

```
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
```

...

```
var posts = $(".post"), // our elements
    postsPos = [], // caсhe for positions
    postsCur = -1, // cache for current
    targetOffset = 50; // position from top of window where you want to make post current

// filling postsPos with positions
posts.each(function(){
    postsPos.push($(this).offset().top);
});

// on window scroll
$(window).bind("scroll", function(){
  // get target post number
  var targ = postsPos.binarySearch($(window).scrollTop() + targetOffset);
  // only if we scrolled to another post
  if (targ != postsCur) {
    // set new cur
    postsCur = targ;
    // moving cur class
    posts.removeClass("cur").eq(targ).addClass("cur");
  }
});

// binary search with little tuning on return to get nearest from bottom
Array.prototype.binarySearch = function(find) {
  var low = 0, high = this.length - 1,
      i, comparison;
  while (low <= high) {
    i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (this[i] < find) { low = i + 1; continue; };
    if (this[i] > find) { high = i - 1; continue; };
    return i;
  }
  return this[i] > find ? i-1 : i;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't bind scroll event to all the divs but only to `window` instead. Then, you should check whether one of the divs overlap with the target point by making a simple calculation of the element offset values.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event)
{
    var isCaptured = capture();
    console.log(isCaptured);
});

function capture()
{
    var c = $('.box'); //this is the divs
    var t = $('#target'); //this is the target element
    var cPos = c.offset(); var tPos = t.offset();

    var overlapY = (cPos.top <= tPos.top + t.height() && cPos.top + c.height() >= tPos.top);
    var overlapX = (cPos.left <= tPos.left + t.width() && cPos.left + c.width() >= tPos.left);
    return overlapY && overlapX;
}
```

Instead of the `$('#target')` element, you can pass top and left (X, Y) offset values directly to the function.

Well, here is a dirty [**demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/YCH2y/).

Comment: This looks pretty good, but the second square wouldn't light up. @antejan has a real nice solution, and the plugin he found seems to be highly scalable. Thanks for the help.